# Can I try LibreOffice 3.4 without installing it?

Tags: libreoffice

I'd like to try the new version but don't want to replace the old version. Are there any binaries I could use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to install LibreOffice in a directory, and run it from there.

For more, see

- [How to run different OpenOffice.org
  versions in parallel (needs
  refinement for LibreOffice)?](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Run_OOo_versions_parallel)
- [How to install LibreOffice in a directory
  for Ubuntu?](http://simos.info/blog/archives/1196)

Answer (score 1):

You could load up a [virtual machine](http://www.virtualbox.org/), install Ubuntu in it and consequently install the [3.4.0-beta5 .deb package](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/pre-releases/) in the Ubuntu install in the VM.

This method obviously won't replace the old version, but *strictly speaking* you are still *installing* LO 3.4.

Comment: Thats indeed the best method as some important things (like desktop integration) cant be tested with parallel installations, but can in a virtual machine. Also: LibreOffice 3.5.0beta2 is available in Ubuntu precise: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/1:3.5.0~beta2-2ubuntu3